# winforms how to convert the MouseEventArgs e.location to TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs?

Tags: c#, winforms

hi
when i trigger the mouseClick event on a control within a tableLayoutPanel i get the location of the mouse within the cell. how do i convert that location in respect to the tableLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the mouse location to tableLayoutPanel.PointToClient() method.

For more details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx

Comment: Too fast, it has to be converted to screen coordinates first.  Use the clicked control's PointToScreen() method, *then* the panel's PointToClient().